# File explorer not responding upon launch in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have Windows 10, and my File Explorer started hanging. It opens, but right from the start it displays the rotating circle and does nothing.

I checked the integrity of files using **sfc** and the other tool, **dism**:

> sfc /scannow
>   dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

Both tools said that all files are okay. I checked for viruses using two antiviruses (Kaspersky Antivirus and DrWeb Cureit!) - no viruses were found. I downloaded an alternative file manager (FAR) and it worked just fine.

I created another user account in Windows, and logged in using this account, and under this new account my File Explorer is working.

Additional info: the File Explorer "broke down" in the morning, when I woke up to discover that my laptop had shut itself down for some reason during the night. I had left it in the evening in the sleep mode.

There are no printers attached to this laptop, only a USB hard-drive, and it works just fine in the FAR manager. The DVD-reader is empty. I run the **chkdsk** tool and it found no problems on disk C:.

What can I do to fix it in my main Administrator account? What could be wrong with it?

Comment: Have you any network shares mounted? Whenever I get this, it's either because of a network failure on one of these, or on bad media in a USB drive or DVD reader.

Comment: @AFH - no, I have no network shares. The laptop was bought only 2 weeks ago. The DVD reader is empty, the external USB harddrive is fine (FAR manager can use it just fine, as well as my other PC).

Comment: How about network attached printers defined that are not accessible, I've seen those cause this sort of problem too. Check the event viewer for clues as well.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - no, there are no printers attached to this laptop at all. I'm using my stationary PC for printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the freeware software called [MultiDoc Converter](http://www.multidoc-converter.com/en/support/index.html) just now, and File Explorer started responding.

I cannot say for sure that this software was the culprit - after all, my laptop had mysteriously turned off before the problem first arose, and this turning off might have damaged something. But anyway, this move (removing the software) somehow unglitched the glitch.

Now I wonder if there was a way to diagnose this issue and determine somehow that it was this program that halted FE.

P.S. In the end, it turned out that **my HDD was dying**. An ultra-thin Seagate 1 TB model. This could have affected it performance, but it's hard to tell now, I've replaced it with an SSD.